# How to evaluate the finite sum $\sum_{k=0}^n{\alpha \choose k}^2\lambda^k$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Is there a close form expression for the series 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n{\alpha \choose k}^2\lambda^k,\quad \alpha ~ \text{is non-integer}
\end{equation}

As far as I know, there is an identity involving binomial coefficients
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}^2 = {2n \choose n}
\end{equation}
which can be proved using generating function $(1+x)^n(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{2n}$. However similar method can not be applied to the first series.

Is there a way to deal with it ? Thank you !

Comment: I suppose this has to do with gamma function.

Comment: According to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28k%3D0+to+n%29+l%5Ek*gamma%28a%2B1%29%2F%28gamma%28k%2B1%29*gamma%28a-k%2B1%29%29) the closed form is $$(\lambda+1)^\alpha-\dfrac{\Gamma(a+1)\lambda^{n+1}\,_2F_1(1,-\alpha+n+1;n+2;- \lambda)}{\Gamma(n+2)\Gamma(\alpha-n)}$$ where $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is the [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series)

Comment: @Darksonn Can you say more about it?

Comment: @ecook Not really, $\Gamma(x)$ is the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) which is related to factorials, namely for integer $x$ it is true that $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$

Comment: Solutions based on hypergeometric functions ${}_2F_1$ are really *rewritings* of the original formula.

Comment: It would brought helpful if touch could there did you get such a question or the source or context or any other info

Answer (score 0):

A standard expression for the $n$th Legendre polynomial is $\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_0^n{n\choose k}^2(x-1)^{n-k}(x+1)^k$.

So that gives immediately the expression $$(1-x)^nP_n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

Comment: This is only true for the $\alpha=n$ case of the OP---which, since the OP asks explicitly for $\alpha$ non-integer, is not the question at hand.