# Closed form solution for $\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n \choose j}^{2}x^{j}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients

As the title suggests, I'm interested to see if there is a closed form solution to

\begin{equation}\label{q}
\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n \choose j}^{2}x^{j}~.
\end{equation}

This can be seen as a generalisation of

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} {n \choose j}^{2} = {2n \choose n}~,$$

where $x=1$ in the title question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914709/how-to-evaluate-the-finite-sum-sum-k-0n-alpha-choose-k2-lambdak?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}^2 x^j = (1-x)^n P_n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

where $P_n( \cdot )$ is the Legendre polynomial.

Comment: I would love to know why this correct answer to a subtle problem received a downvote.

Comment: Thanks very much David, very interesting indeed! Today's entertainment is sorted