# Closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{n}{k}^2 x^k$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> I need a closed form for the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{n}{k}^2 x^k$$ where $0<x<1$

Let $y=x^{1/2}$. The above expression can be rewritten as

$$\int_0^{1 } \left(\sum_{k=0}^j \binom{n}{k}y^k e^{2\pi ikt} \right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^j \binom{n}{k}y^k e^{-2\pi ikt} \right) \ dt.$$
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For future readers: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/915004) answers only the particular case $j=n$ of he OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple does this sum in terms of hypergeometrics:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{n}{k}^2 x^k = \\
\;{}_2F_1\left(-n,-n;1;x\right)
-\binom{n}{j+1}^2 x^{j+1}\;{}_3F_2\left(1,-n+j+1,-n+j+1;2+j,2+j;x\right)
$$

Comment: +1 for your answer.

Comment: Do we have a nice integral representation of our sum?

Comment: I think that you forgot a multiplying factor $x^{j+1}$  at the end of the rhs. Cheers :-)